# HTTP POST not displaying results

Tags: c#, html, web-scraping, httpwebrequest

Trying to POST a webrequest but not getting the actual results.. webrequest not getting submit. Previously this code was working fine in 2018. I'm not sure if they changed something at their end. I copied all the latest parameters, and other stuff from fiddler. Is there anyone please look into it as my deadline for the actual project is very tight and this code is just an integral part of the main project and was assuming it is functional already.. already spent few hours on this..

```
CookieContainer _cookies = new CookieContainer();
string urls = "https://ww3.freddiemac.com/loanlookup?Phone=&Email=&Contact=&lang=en&fname=TEST&lname=PERSON&strt_nbr=123&unit_num=&strt_name=FAKE STREET&strt_suffix=&addr_city=CHICAGO&addr_state=IL&addr_zip=60628&ssn=1234&Verify=Yes";
                    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urls);
                    request.Host = "ww3.freddiemac.com";
                    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36 Edg/83.0.478.61";
                    request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9";
                    WebHeaderCollection myWebHeaderCollection = request.Headers;
                    myWebHeaderCollection.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9");
                    request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip, deflate, br";
                    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                    request.Method = "POST";
                    request.Referer = "https://ww3.freddiemac.com/loanlookup";
                    var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
                    var postBytes = encoding.GetBytes(urls);
                    request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.None;
                    request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
                    request.CookieContainer = _cookies;
                    request.KeepAlive = true;
                    var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                    requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
                    requestStream.Close();
                    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                    
                    string html;
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        html = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                    
                    if (html.Contains("No. Our records show"))
                    {
                        _qualified = false;
                    }
```

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? Any exceptions?

Comment: No. no exceptions but it gives me the same page content without processing it.. Ideally it should process the request using parameters I provided and return the result page https://ww3.freddiemac.com/loanlookup/not_fm_owned.html content where it actually says "No. Our records show that Freddie Mac is not the owner of your mortgage."

Comment: @Crowcoder any idea? I am able to process this request through selenium but wanted to use HTTPWebRequest..

Comment: If you get that message from this code but it works from Selenium then you should suspect your query string. I would start with removing the trailing slash in the url so it is `...loanlookup?Phone...` instead of `...loanlookup/?Phone...`

Comment: Nop.. no change after removing the slash..

Comment: Is this necessary to send something for submit button in parameters? I guess no?

Comment: I'm really wondering why you are doing this anyway. I can't think of a legitimate reason to try to get information about other people's mortgages.

Comment: As I said before it is just an integral part of main project.. before looking into peoples records we takes their consent and if they refused we skip this check.

Comment: You are doing the request correctly since you are receiving a valid response. Either the person you are submitting does not have a Freddie Mac mortgage, or you have used incorrect parameter values, or they have changed how it works. Web scraping is always fragile because websites constantly change. I can't help with any of those problems unless I get a mortgage myself so I can see how the site works.

Comment: Thanks for your time and looking into it.. the parameters I provided here are just fake/dummy info and actual website gives record not found result and that is what I'm actually trying to get through this code.. I want record not found page but this request is giving me the start page content and not processing.. I just noticed that they changed their frontend from HTML to HTML5 do you thing is this something related to the problem?

Comment: I don't really have time to dig into it, but it appears to me when I view the network trace in Chrome dev tools that the request goes to https://ww3.freddiemac.com/loanlookup/SearchResult.jsp and it takes x-www-form-urlencoded POST body, not a GET with query string parameters.